# Odroid and receive data via USB

Tags: android

I have a question about receiving data via USB on odroid. I want to connect odroid via usb with other device. From this other device I want to send bytes to odroid.
1) Is there any samples how can I receive some bytes via usb?
2) Is there any delay to receive data from other device via USB? I want to send data couple time per second. This is possible?

Comment: http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G137510300620

Comment: Fantastic!! The problem is that now I want 10 of those!!!!

Comment: ha ha, I know, nice device, but I still don't know that is any delay when I send data to Android device via USB :)

Comment: Well, I really have no clue. I just did my experiments sending data to and from an Arduino via BlueTooth.

Comment: and how this connection works? Any delays?